# D2 - Mods work on Mac

Tags: mods, diablo-ii

Has anyone tried perfect drop mod or hero editor on a macintosh? I recently got D2 working for a Mac Yosemite, but not sure if any mods with work or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes the mods work. The perfect drop mod you are talking about replace 1 file in your D2 folder. The file that is replaced just basically redoes the drop rate and rolls, it doesn't change anything else that actually makes the game run differently, so the platform doesn't matter.